# PHP selecting only 4 from multidimensional array and shuffling

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I have the following PHP multidimensional array, I'm looking to try select 4 random items and then show them with the title, image and text. With the code I've used I seem to get a single number which is randomized and not what I need.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
        array(
            "image" => "",
            "title" => "Open 7 days.",
            "text" => "We’re open 7 days a week."
        ),
        array(
            "image" => "",
            "title" => "Well done",
            "text" => "Well done you done great."
        ),
        array(
            "image" => "",
            "title" => "Rice",
            "text" => "Various flavours"
        ),
        array(
            "image" => "",
            "title" => "Rooms",
            "text" => "Roomy rooms for a roomyful time"
        ),
        array(
            "image" => "",
            "title" => "Keep in touch.",
            "text" => "Stay in touchwith us as we'll miss you"
        ),
        array(
            "image" => "",
            "title" => "Location",
            "text" => "We'll show you where we are."
        ),
        array(
            "image" => "",
            "title" => "The Home",
            "text" => "See our home page"
        )
    );

    print_r(array_rand($arr));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're picking only one entry, [`array_rand()`](https://www.php.net/array_rand) returns a single key for a random entry. If you use the `num` to specify how many keys should be picked, then it returns `num` number of keys of random entries.

The function only returns the keys of the random entries and not the array chunks itself. You'll have to manually build the array from the returned keys:

```
// get the random keys
$keys = array_rand($arr, 4);

// initialize result array
$result = array();

// loop through the keys and build the array
foreach ($keys as $k) {
    $result[] = $arr[$k];
}

print_r($result);
```

**Update**

From a quick benchmark, it seems `array_rand()` is signficantly faster than using `shuffle()` for larger arrays. The benchmark was done on an array having `14336` elements with `10000` iterations each.

The results obtained on my dev machine were as follows:

- Number of elements in the array - `14336`
- Number of iterations for each method - `10000`
- `array_rand()` version took 4.659 seconds
- `shuffle()` version took 15.071 seconds

The code used for benchmarking can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/amalmurali47/9213340).

Answer (score 1):

## No need to loop !

### `shuffle()` and `array_slice()` does the job.

Simply `shuffle` your array such that it rearranges the entries , now pick the first `4` items using `array_slice`.

---

```
shuffle($arr);
print_r(array_slice($arr,0,4));
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/105571)

Comment: The problem with `shuffle()` is that it mangles your array keys (not in this case, though). It should also be noted that `array_rand()` will *not* return duplicate elements if you request more than one random entry, whereas `shuffle()` will. This is a valid solution, but I'd personally stick with `array_rand()`  :)

Comment: @AmalMurali: `array_slice()` in this case gives the first 4 elements, how can they be duplicates?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: If the array values are in random order, there's a possibility that it will.

Comment: @AmalMurali, Can you provide some test case that `shuffle` fails in this scenario ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: I didn't say it would fail. I said there's a probability that it returns duplicate elements. From a quick benchmark, it also appears that `array_rand()` is significantly faster when working with larger arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the `$num` parameter [array_rand()](http://php.net/array_rand)

```
print_r(array_rand($arr, 4));
```

To display all:

```
foreach(array_rand($arr, 4) as $key) {
    echo $arr[$key]['text'] ."\n";
    //etc
}
```

Comment: This gives me `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 11` how would I use this to print my array values